# Remote debug console application in NetBeans that needs input

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am trying to debug a project, that i run remotely on a raspberry pi.
The problem is, that the project is a console application that also needs console inputs to work.
But how can i send console inputs to the application ?
I tried typing something in the usual output window, because i read that you can use it like the console, but either this does not work with NetBEans 8 or it does not work with remode debugging.
Is there any other way ?
I can open a SSH terminal, but how do i switch it to use the input/putput of the running debug session ?